# How to loop through List<dynamic>

Tags: c#, list, dynamic, dictionary

I have a Class which contains a dynamic List, which I manage to access like this.

```
foreach (var c in objects)
{
    foreach (dynamic i in c.data)
    {
        var ss = i;
    }
}
```

The Class

```
public class iUpdateGrid
{
    public int type { get; set; }
    public string session { get; set; }
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
    public string ip { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string station { get; set; }
    public List<iGridData> h_33 { get; set; }
}
public class iGridData
{
    public string table { get; set; }
    public List<dynamic> data { get; set; }
}
```

"ss" contains now a list of objects, however have no idea how to get these values to a Dictionary or list.
One note I also need to adjust the key names.

Things I tried to do:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in i)
{
    string key = kv.Key;
    string value = kv.Value;
}
```

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' because 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Also the Dynamic objects does not give me the options to access the key and/or value.

Any help how I can loop through this would be very welcome.

also when I put this on runtime "i" says its a  System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary however can access this also.

Solution:

Made little chance to solution as provided, but this worked for me:

```
        foreach (var c in objects)
        {
            foreach (dynamic i in c.data)
            {
                foreach (var v in (i as IDictionary<string, object>))
                {
                    string key = v.Key;
                    object value = v.Value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: the question is "how to I convert c.data to a dictionary", right?  If so, what is the _type_ of `c.data`?

Comment: also, the error "'System.Collections.IEnumerable' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'" makes no sense. It does contain a `GetEnumerator`.

Comment: c.data is a dynamic List<dynamic>

Comment: Dictionary<dynamic,dynamic>

Comment: No does not work, already tried

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you're trying to do, but if the complier doesn't know what sort of data it is, then it's up to you to cast it, no? I've did a couple of test that seemed to work fine, not sure how to add as comment within a code block though.

Comment: `var dynList = new List<dynamic>{1,2,3};
foreach(dynamic dyn in dynList)
    Console.WriteLine(dyn);
dynList = new List<dynamic> { new Dictionary<string, int> { { "hi", 1 },{ "ho", 2 } }};
foreach (dynamic dyn in dynList)
    Console.WriteLine((dyn as Dictionary<string,int>).First().Key);`

Comment: Yeah your update is getting there. You don't need the third foreach loop because a Dicitonary<> is only ever one element.
just cast it and extract values:
var item = i as IDictionary<string, object>;
var key = item.Key;
var value = item.value;

Comment: Unfortunatly I need because there are multiple objects there and need to adjust them, but thanks for the comment )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    foreach (var v in (i as IEnumerable<object>))
    {
        if (v is KeyValuePair<string, string>)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
        else if (v is List<string>)
        {
            //Do stuff
        }

        else throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
```

Comment: I get error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on (i as IEnumerable<object>)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var c in objects)
{
    foreach (dynamic i in c.data)
    {
        var property_value = i.GetType().GetProperty("PROPERTY_NAME").GetValue(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Please **describe** your answer and not just using **code**. Otherwise may your answer will be deleted!